# Is there a non-unital ring such that one of its quotient ring is unital?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a non unital ring, but it has an ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ is unital, does this kind of animal exist?

This problem arouse when I try to show “$R$ is unital, $R/I$ is division ring, then $I$ is maximal. “ I am wondering whether the condition $R$ is unital can be dropped or not.

Thank you in advance.

By the way, is this kind of problem meaningful? I am pretty addicted to this kind of problems but it seems that nobody cares about it.

Comment: Are your rings commutative? Is your ideal both sided?

Comment: Technically $R/R$ is unital.

Comment: @N.S. Thats not interesting

Answer (score 9):

$R = 2 \mathbb Z$, $I = ( 6 )$

Comment: What is the 1 in $R/I$?

Comment: It is $4 + 6\Bbb Z$.

Comment: For a moment my brain froze... I wonder if one can argue directly that if $R$ is any ring (not necessarily unital) and $I$ an ideal such that $R/I$ has carnality a prime number, then $R/I$ must be a field, and hence unital. I suppose that this is true....

Comment: Sure, one can do that.

Comment: @N.S. Try quotienting this ring by the ideal of multiples of 4 to discover the answer to your question.

Comment: The comment about $R/I$ having a prime number of elements isn't quite right. E.g., take $R$ to be $\Bbb{Z}$ as an additive group with $xy=0$ for every $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the non-unital commutative ring

$R = \Bbb Z \oplus 2\Bbb Z, \tag 1$

with component-wise addition and multiplication.  Let $I \subset R$ be the ideal

$I = \{(0, b) \mid  b \in 2\Bbb Z \}; \tag 2$

then $R$ has no unit, but

$R/I \simeq \Bbb Z. \tag 3$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can happen. Consider e.g. $R:=\{p\in\Bbb Z[x]:p(0)\in 2\Bbb Z\}  $ and $I:=(2x-2,x^2-x)$. 
Then $2ax+I=2a+I$ for $a\in\Bbb Z$ and by induction, $x^n+I=x+I$, so $x+I$ will act as a multiplicative identity on $R/I$, and by the way, $R/I\cong\Bbb Z$.

Comment: thank you but x^2-x is not in that ring

Comment: Why not? The ring contains $x$ and should be closed on multiplication and subtraction. Only odd *numbers* are missing.

Comment: Sorry my brain got stuck and you're right. Brilliant construction

Comment: $2\mathbb Z[x]$ does not contain $x$, as by definition it contains all polynomials with coefficients in $2 \mathbb Z$.  I think you mean $$R=\{ P \in \mathbb Z[X] : P(0) \mbox{ is even } \}$$

Comment: Hmm. You're right. Edited.